# Passing property names to type properties

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-generics

I'm trying to type a configuration object whose properties have arbitrary names.
Each arbitrary key name must have a value which is a typed object with some defined property that has, as a value, one of the key names of the parent object.

Here is what i came up with :

```
//parent type
type ParentType<KeyNames extends string> = {
  [k in KeyNames]: ChildType<KeyNames>;
};

//child type
interface ChildType<KeyNames extends string>  {
  oneOfKeys : KeyNames
}
```

The problem is that it's working in the opposite direction i was hoping for.

```
function testFunc<Keynames extends string>(foo:ParentType<Keynames>){
}

//testFunc is infered as testFunc<"bar" | "baz" | "foo">
//i would like for it to be infered as testFunc<"foo" | "bar" | "bal">
testFunc({
  foo: {
    oneOfKeys: "bar"
  },
  bar : {
    oneOfKeys: "baz"
  },
  bal : { //TS is complaining about the "bal" key
    oneOfKeys: "foo"
  }
})
```

I wanted the compiler to check that oneOfkeys what one of the key of the parent object, but instead it checks that the parent key is one of the values of oneOfKeys.
It's like the generic's inference was working bottom-up when i want it to work top-down.

I have tried various other approaches which don't work at all.

Comment: Could you please clarify where you expect an error and where you dont. SHould `oneOfKeys` be validated?

Comment: @captain-yossarian the foo, bar and bal keys should be accepted but "oneOfKeys" : "baz" should be rejected since there is not parent "baz" key.

Answer (score 1):

Passing the whole object to `ParentType` means the compiler won't erroneously infer the keys wrong:

```
type ParentType<O> = {
  [k in keyof O]: ChildType<O>;
};

//child type
interface ChildType<O>  {
  oneOfKeys : keyof O
}

function testFunc<O>(foo:ParentType<O>){
}


testFunc({
  foo: {
    oneOfKeys: "bar"
  },
  bar : {
    oneOfKeys: "baz" // Error
  },
  bal : {
    oneOfKeys: "foo"
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem now is that since there is not constraint on O, foo:ParentType<O> is infered as a big bag of unknown.
The constraint on my object structure is enforced, but i can't do anything with it later.

Answer (score 1):

FIrst of all you need to infer each key and value of function argument:

```js
type Value<Prop extends PropertyKey> = { oneOfKeys: Prop }

function testFunc<
  ParentKey extends PropertyKey,
  Item extends Value<ParentKey>,
  Config extends Record<ParentKey, Item>
>(foo: Config) {}
```

`ParentKey` infers all parent keys.

`Item` infers all nested objects: `{oneOfKeys: string}`

`Config` infers whole config.

More about infering arguments you can find in my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)

Then, you need iterate through infered `Config` and find disallowed values:

```js
type Validation<Config extends Record<PropertyKey, Value<PropertyKey>>> = {
  [Prop in keyof Config]: Config[Prop]['oneOfKeys'] extends keyof Config ? Config[Prop] : Value<never>
}

type Test = Validation<{
  foo: {
    oneOfKeys: "bar"
  },
  bar: {
    oneOfKeys: "baz"
  },
  bal: { //TS is complaining about the "bal" key
    oneOfKeys: "foo"
  }
}>
```

`Validation` - iterates throught every `Config` prop and checks whether `Config[Prop]['oneOfKeys']` extends any parent key. If yes - leavs value as it is, otherwise replace value with `never`.

WHole code:

```js
type Validation<Config extends Record<PropertyKey, Value<PropertyKey>>> = {
  [Prop in keyof Config]: Config[Prop]['oneOfKeys'] extends keyof Config ? Config[Prop] : Value<never>
}

type Test = Validation<{
  foo: {
    oneOfKeys: "bar"
  },
  bar: {
    oneOfKeys: "baz"
  },
  bal: { 
    oneOfKeys: "foo"
  }
}>

type Value<Prop extends PropertyKey> = { oneOfKeys: Prop }

function testFunc<
  ParentKey extends PropertyKey,
  Item extends Value<ParentKey>,
  Config extends Record<ParentKey, Item>
>(foo: Validation<Config>) {}

testFunc({
  foo: {
    oneOfKeys: "bar"
  },
  bar: {
    oneOfKeys: "baz" // error
  },
  bal: { 
    oneOfKeys: "foo"
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WkjR9m)

Comment: Thank for you help, but your code doesn't seems to work, i get no error.

Comment: @VincentJ my bad. I forgot to wrap `Config` into `Validator`. It should work now

Comment: Thank you. I am a bit disapointed that there no easier way to do this. Also it produces rather cryptic error message for the end user.

Comment: Instead of NEVER you can use any message. Believe me, this is not the hardest way :D